# Ways to validate converted code from FORTRAN to C

Tags: c, fortran

I have converted around 90+ fortran files into C files using a tool and I need to validate that the conversion is good or not.

Can you give me some ideas on how best to ensure that the functionality has been preserved through the translation?

Comment: Compile and debug?  Welcome to the seventies.  There are certainly better methods in the 21st century. :-)

Comment: @Patrick I would agree with unit tests but if the code has not been designed for testing you may need to refactor first. Then to write a huge amount of code for testing (supposing you can get a good code coverage without a BIG refactoring maybe in both Fortran and C code). Unit tests are mandatory for serious coding but they are good to test **code quality** and **not conversion quality**. You may find that you need **more time to refactor** and code tests **than to rewrite** from scratch with tests in mind (TDD world)...

Comment: @Adriano Tests are extremely helpful when refactoring as well.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze I completely agree but when code has not been written with tests in mind then it could be very hard to write tests (and this is even more true for **pure C** code where you call **global functions**, no classes to mock, no dependency injection, nothing to make tests easy).

Comment: @Adriano You start somewhere. Maybe the kind of first tests in that case would be to just "extract the behavior" so the refactored code's behavior can be compared with something. That's not functional testing, just making sure you get exactly the same thing after refactoring, whether it's correct behavior or not is secondary.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze yes, if he can test **blocks** then it's OK!

Answer (score 3):

You need verification tests that exercise those fortran functions. Then you run those tests against the c code.

You can use unit test technology/methodology. In fact I can't see how else you would prove that the conversion is correct.

In lots of unit test methodologies you would write the tests in the same language as the code, but in this case I recommend very very strongly to pick one language and one code base to exercise both sets of functions. Also don't worry about be trying to create pure unit tests rather use the techniques to give you coverage of all the use that the fortran code was supposed to handle.

Answer (score 2):

Use unit tests.

First write your unit tests on the Fortran code and check whether they all run correctly, then rewrite them in C and run those.

The problem in this approach is that you also need to rewrite your unit test, which you normally don't do when refactoring code (except for API changes).  This means that you might end up debugging your ported unit testing code as well, beside the actual code.

Therefore, it might be better to write testing code that contains minimal logic and only write the results of the functions to a file.  Then you can rewrite this minimal testing code in C, generate the same files and compare the files.

Comment: I don't understand why you think that the unit tests need to be rewritten.  It's relatively easy to write Fortran or C (or Python or any one of a myriad languages) tests which at link time are provided with the routine to be tested whether that routine is originally in Fortran or C.

Comment: I agree, but linking Fortran with C might not always that easy (depends on the platform).  I managed a mixed Fortran/C application 15 years ago and stopped doing it 10 years ago after I had to patch the C runtime source code to get it working for Fortran.  At a certain moment it was easier to convert everything to C than maintaining the mixed Fortran/C environment.

Comment: You seem unaware of the facilities for interoperability with C that Fortran introduced into the language standard in 2003 and which all the currently available compilers (at least all the ones I know of) implement.  You turn your back for 10 years and ...

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did for a "similar" task (comparing fortran 90 to fortran 90 + OpenACC GPU accelerated code):

1. Analyze what's the output of each Fortran module.
2. Write these output arrays to .dat files.
3. Copy the .dat files into a reference folder.
4. Write the output of the converted modules to files (either CSV or binary). Use the same filename for convenience.
5. Make a python script that compares the two versions.

I used convenience functions like these in fortran (analogous for 1D, 2D case):

```
subroutine write3DToFile(path, array, n1, n2, n3)
   use pp_vardef
   use pp_service, only: find_new_mt
   implicit none

   !input arguments
   real(kind = r_size), intent(in) :: array(n1,n2,n3)
   character(len=*), intent(in) :: path
   integer(4) :: n1
   integer(4) :: n2
   integer(4) :: n3

   !temporary
   integer(4) :: imt

   call find_new_mt(imt)

   open(imt, file = path, form = 'unformatted', status = 'replace')
   write(imt) array
   close(imt)
 end subroutine write3DToFile
```

In python I used the following script for reading binary Fortran data and comparing it. Note: Since you want to convert to C you would have to adapt it such that you can read the data produced by C instead of Fortran.

```
from optparse import OptionParser
import struct
import sys
import math

def unpackNextRecord(file, readEndianFormat, numOfBytesPerValue):
    header = file.read(4)
    if (len(header) != 4):
        #we have reached the end of the file
        return None

    headerFormat = '%si' %(readEndianFormat)
    headerUnpacked = struct.unpack(headerFormat, header)
    recordByteLength = headerUnpacked[0]
    if (recordByteLength % numOfBytesPerValue != 0):
        raise Exception, "Odd record length."
        return None
    recordLength = recordByteLength / numOfBytesPerValue

    data = file.read(recordByteLength)
    if (len(data) != recordByteLength):
        raise Exception, "Could not read %i bytes as expected. Only %i bytes read." %(recordByteLength, len(data))
        return None

    trailer = file.read(4)
    if (len(trailer) != 4):
        raise Exception, "Could not read trailer."
        return None
    trailerUnpacked = struct.unpack(headerFormat, trailer)
    redundantRecordLength = trailerUnpacked[0]
    if (recordByteLength != redundantRecordLength):
        raise Exception, "Header and trailer do not match."
        return None

    dataFormat = '%s%i%s' %(readEndianFormat, recordLength, typeSpecifier)
    return struct.unpack(dataFormat, data)

def rootMeanSquareDeviation(tup, tupRef):
    err = 0.0
    i = 0
    for val in tup:
        err = err + (val - tupRef[i])**2
        i = i + 1
    return math.sqrt(err)

##################### MAIN ##############################
#get all program arguments
parser = OptionParser()
parser.add_option("-f", "--file", dest="inFile",
                  help="read from FILE", metavar="FILE", default="in.dat")
parser.add_option("--reference", dest="refFile",
                  help="reference FILE", metavar="FILE", default="ref.dat")
parser.add_option("-b", "--bytesPerValue", dest="bytes", default="4")
parser.add_option("-r", "--readEndian", dest="readEndian", default="big")
parser.add_option("-v", action="store_true", dest="verbose")

(options, args) = parser.parse_args()

numOfBytesPerValue = int(options.bytes)
if (numOfBytesPerValue != 4 and numOfBytesPerValue != 8):
    print "Unsupported number of bytes per value specified."
    sys.exit()
typeSpecifier = 'f'
if (numOfBytesPerValue == 8):
    typeSpecifier = 'd'

readEndianFormat = '>'
if (options.readEndian == "little"):
    readEndianFormat = '<'

inFile = None
refFile = None
try: 
    #prepare files
    inFile = open(str(options.inFile),'r')
    refFile = open(str(options.refFile),'r')

    i = 0
    while True:
        passedStr = "pass"
        i = i + 1
        unpackedRef = None
        try: 
            unpackedRef = unpackNextRecord(refFile, readEndianFormat, numOfBytesPerValue)
        except(Exception), e:
            print "Error reading record %i from %s: %s" %(i, str(options.refFile), e)
            sys.exit()

        if (unpackedRef == None):
            break;

        unpacked = None
        try:
            unpacked = unpackNextRecord(inFile, readEndianFormat, numOfBytesPerValue)
        except(Exception), e:
            print "Error reading record %i from %s: %s" %(i, str(options.inFile), e)
            sys.exit()

        if (unpacked == None):
            print "Error in %s: Record expected, could not load record it" %(str(options.inFile))
            sys.exit()

        if (len(unpacked) != len(unpackedRef)):
            print "Error in %s: Record %i does not have same length as reference" %(str(options.inFile), i)
            sys.exit()

        #analyse unpacked data
        err = rootMeanSquareDeviation(unpacked, unpackedRef)
        if (abs(err) > 1E-08):
            passedStr = "FAIL <-------"
        print "%s, record %i: Mean square error: %e; %s" %(options.inFile, i, err, passedStr)

        if (options.verbose):
            print unpacked

except(Exception), e:
    print "Error: %s" %(e)

finally:
    #cleanup
    if inFile != None:
        inFile.close()

    if refFile != None:
        refFile.close()
```